# Why can i only insert into database certain date using datepicker?

Tags: php, html

I do not know why i can only insert into my database certain dates, eg. 4 feb 2017, 11 feb 2017 but some other days it doesnt work. I have been trying it for very long please help thank you.

This is my script `<script>`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ yearRange:"-0:+1", minDate: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',  beforeShowDay: function (date)
    {
        var array = <?php echo json_encode($dateArray); ?>;
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
    }
    });
});
  </script>
```

My database date is stored as date.

```
       if(!empty($_POST['datepicker'])){
            if(strtotime($_POST['datepicker']) > time()) {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datepicker'])); 
            }

            }
            else
            {
            $date=null;
            $dateerr = "<b><font color='red'>Please select a date</font></b></p>";
            }

       if($date){

            session_start();

            $mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO booking (ffg, date,sf ,asd)
                                    VALUES ('$wdd','$date','$fg','$fgg')");

            $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result == TRUE && $stmt->affected_rows>0) 
            {
              echo"yay";
            }
           }
            $stmt->close();
            $mysqli->close();
```